# Plug-in "org.tizen.web.zimlaunch" was unable to instantiate class

Tags: ide, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am usin Tizen IDE for Wearable. During build I had a power failure and my PC went down. Since then IDE does not work. Whatever action is performed this error occurs:

> Plug-in "org.tizen.web.zimlaunch" was unable to instantiate class > "org.tizen.web.zimlaunch.deployer.ZimLaunchDelegate".
>   org/tizen/web/project/configuration/ConfigurationException

I tried to uninstal the IDE and install it again, I deleted all the files I knew to be connected to the IDE nothing helped.

Do you know what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it.

Remove metadata folder from workspace. Doing this will demand to reimport all of your projects but fixes the problem.

> \workspace\.metadata